# AppDynamics doesn't monitor calls from Hystrix app

Tags: java, rest, netflix, hystrix, appdynamics

I develop common java web app. I use `Hystrix` in my app, actually I have a `REST client` whose methods wrapped in `hystrix` commands. My web app uses this rest client to communicate with remote server. 
My web app is configured as described in `hystrix` [wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-examples-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) (it's needed to calculate statistics for `hystrix` dashboard). To monitor my web app I use `AppDynamics` tool, but after I started using `rest client` based on `Hystrix` all calls from my web app aren't being displayed in `AppDynamics`. When I switched implementation to client without Hystrix everything is working well as expected. Maybe somebody knows what is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You need show us the details what's the change you did, before and after setting as well, otherwise no one can guess it.

Comment: Hystrix uses in the standard configuration a thread pool to implement timeouts. I suppose this confuses AppDynamics. Configure Hystrix to use a semaphore instead and give it a try. I will post it as an answer if this is the case.